Unexpected character lexer error when using template literal in HTML
I use template literal to parametrize class name in HTML:
<div class="myclass__spinner ${num ? `myclass-progress__color-${num}` : ''}">
This is Aurelia view:
<template bindable="num, small, medium">
    <div class="myclass__spinner ${num ? `myclass-progress__color-${num}` : ''}">

Bindable param "num" is passed to the view and depending on it the class is defined.
However, I get the following error in browser console:
aurelia-binding.js:2551 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`] at column 6 in expression [num ? `myclass-progress__color-${num}` : '']
    at Scanner.error (aurelia-binding.js:2551:1)
    at Scanner.scanToken (aurelia-binding.js:2383:1)
    at Lexer.lex (aurelia-binding.js:2299:1)
    at new ParserImplementation (aurelia-binding.js:2713:1)
    at Parser.parse (aurelia-binding.js:2701:1)
    at TemplatingBindingLanguage.parseInterpolation (aurelia-templating-binding.js:753:1)
    at TemplatingBindingLanguage.inspectAttribute (aurelia-templating-binding.js:627:1)
    at ViewCompiler._compileElement (aurelia-templating.js:2214:1)
    at ViewCompiler._compileNode (aurelia-templating.js:2030:1)
    at ViewCompiler._compileNode (aurelia-templating.js:2052:1)

How can this be fixed?

If you use template literals, the you should surround the template in backticks. ${ `some text` } is not a template literal because the backticks are inside.

Please note for future questions that it's important to provide all the context of your code. In this example you've only provided the string value and not shown how you're actually declaring the string itself.

Given that the question is tagged with [tag:aurelia-templating], I assume the HTML is part of a view in Aurelia.

Yes, this is Aurelia view. Sorry, I've updated the initial post with more details.

I don't know Aurelia, but in straight up Javascript, you need to move the back ticks to the outside of the string and change the way you concatenate the second num.
The string would need to be:
<div class=`myclass__spinner ${num ? 'myclass_progress__color_'+num : ''}`>

